# Web app in C# works good where VS2013 is installed but not in WebServers

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013, webdeploy, office365-apps

That's it, the code runs smoothly in test enviroment (Using windows 8.1, Visual studio 2013 with SP4).

The point is that my code doesn't connect to the MSOnline when it's deployed to a production enviroment. I just can't figure out what's wrong when I do the deployment using Webdeploy option...
I just can't find what's wrong with it... and I really need help.
It runs a powershell using the MSOnline and extended modules.

I  did install the modules MSOnline:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39267
the MSOnline module for 64 bits.
and this script:

```
set A=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
set M1=MSOnline
set M2=MSOnlineExtended
set B=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
IF NOT EXIST %B%\%M1% mkdir %B%\%M1%
IF NOT EXIST %B%\%M2% mkdir %B%\%M2%
xcopy %A%\%M1% %B%\%M1% /s /e
xcopy %A%\%M2% %B%\%M2% /s /e
pause
```

That prepares the modules from 32bits to run in 64 bits.

It runs good where the visual studio 2013 is installed, but when I did the deploy to the WebServers... just doens't work... I have tried to find something similar here and in internet with no joy and no luck... I appreciate any help you could give me, Thanks !

Here's my code in ASP.NET:

```
 <%@ Page Title="Domain Info" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"     CodeBehind="DomainInfo.aspx.cs" Inherits="LSO365Portal.DomainInfo" %>
 <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.Master" %>
 <asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent">
 <section class="featured">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <hgroup class="title">

           <h1> <%= titulo %> </h1>
           <h3>Here where you'll find interesting information about your Office 365 Domains.</h3>
        </hgroup>
    </div>
</section>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<h3> Execute Script pressing the following button</h3>
<p>
    <asp:Table HorizontalAlign="Center" runat="server">
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:Button ID="Execute" runat="server" Text="Execute Script" OnClick="RunScript" Height="35px" Width="150px" />
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
  </p>
 <h3> Results</h3>
  <p>
    <asp:Table ID="SubsTable" runat="server" GridLines="Both" HorizontalAlign="Center"  CssClass="ResultTables">
    </asp:Table>
  </p>
  <h3> Elapsed</h3>
 <asp:Label ID="EnlapsedLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

  <h3> Status</h3>
  <p>
  <asp:TextBox ID="Stats" runat="server" Width="850px" Height="80px" ReadOnly="True" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
  </p>

  </asp:Content>
```

Here's the code behind:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.Collections.ObjectModel; //Collection<T>
 using System.Management.Automation;
 using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
 using System.Text; //stringbuilder
 using System.Security; //securestring
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 using System.Diagnostics; //stopwatch

namespace LSO365Portal
{

public partial class DomainInfo : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected const string PasswordMask = "*********************************************************************************************************************************";
    public String titulo = "Domains Information in Office 365";
    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

    StringBuilder status = new StringBuilder();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){}
    //protected void UpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //{
    //    DateStampLabel.Text = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();
    //}
    protected void RunScript(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        watch.Reset();            
        watch.Start();

        // Clean the Result TextBox
        Stats.Text = string.Empty;
        status.Clear();
        //check1
        status.AppendLine("watch reseted and status cleared");
        StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();

        try
        {
            //            Import-Module MSOnline OPC #1
            InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();

            iss.ImportPSModule(new string[] { "MSOnline,MSOnlineExtended" });
            //check2
            //status.AppendLine("initial state and MSOnline Loaded");
            Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);
            rs.Open();
            //status.AppendLine(rs.InitialSessionState.ToString());
            //check3
            //status.AppendLine("Created and open runspace");

            Pipeline pipeLine = rs.CreatePipeline();

            string un = String.Empty;
            string pw = String.Empty;
            TextBox tbUn = (TextBox)Master.FindControl("Username");
            TextBox tbPw = (TextBox)Master.FindControl("Textpwd");

            //check 4
            //status.AppendLine("Created pipeline");
            if (tbUn != null && tbPw != null)
            {
                un = tbUn.Text;
                pw = tbPw.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                status.AppendLine("Error trying to find username and password from the master page");
            }

            //Set variables Username and password
            script.AppendLine("$username = '" + un + "';");
                                         //ConvertTo-SecureString      '    MySPW '     –asplaintext –force
            script.AppendLine("$password = Convertto-securestring " + "'" + pw + "'" + "-asplaintext -force");
            script.AppendLine("$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username,$password;");

            // Check Username and password
            script.AppendLine("write-Output $username");
            script.AppendLine("write-Output $password");

            //connect and check connection
            script.AppendLine("Connect-MsolService -credential $cred -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue");
            script.AppendLine("if($?){ write-output 'connected' } else{write-output 'disconnected'}");


            //check 5
               //$DomainInfo = Get-MsolDomain | select Name,Authentication,Capabilities,Status,isDefault,isInitial
            //status.AppendLine("Get-MsolDomain | select Name,Authentication,Capabilities,Status,isDefault,isInitial");
            script.AppendLine("Get-MsolDomain | select Name,Authentication,Capabilities,Status,isDefault,isInitial");
            //Add scripts to the pipeline

            pipeLine.Commands.AddScript(script.ToString());
            //check 7
            status.AppendLine("Added script to pipeline");
            status.AppendLine("this is the script");
            status.AppendLine(script.ToString());

            //execute pipeline and get the results PSObjects
            Collection<PSObject> resultObjects = pipeLine.Invoke();
            //check 8
            status.AppendLine("Total results Objects are: " + resultObjects.Count.ToString());

            foreach (PSObject obj in resultObjects)
            {
                status.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
            }
            //Clear Script and close Runspace
            script.Clear();
            rs.Close();

            if (resultObjects.Count > 0 || resultObjects != null)
            {
                GenerateTable(resultObjects);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException ex)
        {
            status.AppendLine(ex.Message);
        }
        status.AppendLine("Ready");
        Stats.Text = status.ToString();
        watch.Stop();
        double elap = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000;
        EnlapsedLabel.Text = "Work Done in : " + elap.ToString() + " seconds";
    }

    private string SetRowHeadersName(int i)
    {
        //Name,Authentication,Capabilities,Status,isDefault,isInitial
        string text = String.Empty;
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0:
                text = "Name";
                break;
            case 1:
                text = "Authentication";
                break;
            case 2:
                text = "Capabilities";
                break;
            case 3:
                text = "Status";
                break;
            case 4:
                text = "is Default";
                break;
            case 5:
                text = "is Initial";
                break;
            default:
                text = "Error on SetRowHeadersName Function";
                break;
        }
        return text;
    }
    private string SetCellValue(int j, PSObject result)
    {

        string text = string.Empty;
        switch (j)
        {
            //Name,Authentication,Capabilities,Status,isDefault,isInitial
            case 0:
                text = result.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString();
                break;
            case 1:
                text = result.Properties["Authentication"].Value.ToString();
                break;
            case 2:
                text = result.Properties["Capabilities"].Value.ToString();
                break;
            case 3:
                text = result.Properties["Status"].Value.ToString();
                break;
            case 4:
                text = result.Properties["isDefault"].Value.ToString();
                break;
            case 5:
                text = result.Properties["isInitial"].Value.ToString();
                break;
            default:
                text = "Value not found, column:" + j;
                break;
        }
        return text;
    }
    private void GenerateTable(Collection<PSObject> objs)
    {

        int rowsCount = objs.Count;
        //The number of Columns to be generated
        const int colsCount = 6;//You can changed the value of 5 based on you requirements NextLifecycleDate,SkuId,SkuPartNumber,Status,TotalLicenses

        // Now iterate through the table and add your controls
        try
        {
            //ADD HEADER NAMES
            TableRow rowHeader = new TableRow();

            for (int i = 0; i < colsCount; i++)
            {
                //create a new header
                TableCell header = new TableCell();
                //create new label
                Label headertext = new Label();
                //set text of label
                headertext.Text = SetRowHeadersName(i);
                //set unique ID
                header.ID = "headerCell_" + i;
                header.CssClass = "tableheader";
                //add control to the header
                header.Controls.Add(headertext);
                // Add the TableCell to the TableRow
                rowHeader.Cells.Add(header);
            }
            SubsTable.Rows.Add(rowHeader);

            //Add info on PSObjects
            for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
            {
                TableRow row = new TableRow();
                for (int j = 0; j < colsCount; j++)
                {
                    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                    Label tb = new Label();
                    string RowText = string.Empty;
                    cell.CssClass = "tablecell";
                    RowText = SetCellValue(j, objs[i]);
                    tb.Text = RowText;

                    // Set a unique ID for each TextBox added
                    tb.ID = "Row_" + i + "Col_" + j;
                    // Add the control to the TableCell
                    cell.Controls.Add(tb);
                    // Add the TableCell to the TableRow
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                }

                // And finally, add the TableRow to the Table
                SubsTable.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            //Sore the current Rows Count in ViewState
            ViewState["RowsCount"] = rowsCount;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            status.Append("Error in GenerateTable() " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Do you have access to Web Server ? Mainly webserver powershell

Comment: Yes I do, I have a webserver to test it, I have a local vm as well to do the steps of publishing over and over again. For documentation purposes

Answer (score 0):

Likely you need to install something that is installed by default with Visual Studio (e.g. the correct version of .NET, or one of the libraries you are using). Are you throwing any errors? You may need to look in the Event Log to see them.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I've got some information in the powershell log.
Information events 600,400,403

Comment: Nothing in the event log? How about the IIS logs? You should be throwing 500 level errors.

Comment: I can add you the event log file at any email you give me from the webserver... Thanks for your reply again